# How to programmatically link a contact number?

Tags: android

I want to develop contact application with basic CRUD operations with Contacts, and Mostly Link Contact Numbers using Android.

Comment: what do you mean by *Link android contact number*? WHat exactly is a problem for you to develop such an app?

Comment: I want to get a list of linked contacts and add new link contact

Comment: how do the contacts link? how do you know that they are linked?

Comment: that what I m saying, I m new in android native programming I don't know how to identify that the contact is linked with other?

Comment: is there any way to identify them ?

Comment: It is not clear what *is* that you mean as *Link*. How do you know if contacts are linked? Why do you think that they even are possible to somehow link?

Comment: Just for you to understand: You want something you call *Link contacts*, but likely it called another way because nobody so far understood what you mean. That's why I ask you to explain in other words, or show some example of what you mean by *Link Contacts*

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = MyActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS = 1;
private Uri uriContact;
private String contactID;     // contacts unique ID


/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void onClickSelectContact(View btnSelectContact) {

    // using native contacts selection
    // Intent.ACTION_PICK = Pick an item from the data, returning what was selected.
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + data.toString());
        uriContact = data.getData();

        retrieveContactName();
        retrieveContactNumber();
        retrieveContactPhoto();

    }
}

private void retrieveContactPhoto() {

    Bitmap photo = null;

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(contactID)));

        if (inputStream != null) {
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_contact);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }

        assert inputStream != null;
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void retrieveContactNumber() {

    String contactNumber = null;

    // getting contacts ID
    Cursor cursorID = getContentResolver().query(uriContact,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
            null, null, null);

    if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {

        contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    }

    cursorID.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Contact ID: " + contactID);

    // Using the contact ID now we will get contact phone number
    Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

            new String[]{contactID},
            null);

    if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
        contactNumber = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    }

    cursorPhone.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Contact Phone Number: " + contactNumber);
}

private void retrieveContactName() {

    String contactName = null;

    // querying contact data store
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriContact, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        // DISPLAY_NAME = The display name for the contact.
        // HAS_PHONE_NUMBER =   An indicator of whether this contact has at least one phone number.

        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }
    cursor.close();
    Log.d(TAG, "Contact Name: " + contactName);
}
}
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select a Contact"
        android:onClick="onClickSelectContact" />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/img_contact"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
           android:contentDescription="Contacts Image"
            />
```

and add this to menifest file :

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: Hey, @bugfreeraamon can you please give full source code. or library file which being used there? I m new in android native programming.

Comment: doing other people's job instead of them makes people even more lazy. Please avoid answering **obviously off-topic question**